# Objective C - application crashes when creating an array of strings, am I crazy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

If i try to use this simple code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

    NSString *stringMer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK COOL"] ;
    NSString *stringMer2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OK COOL"];

    NSArray *truc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stringMer,stringMer2];
}
```

My application crashes ("unable to read unknown load command 0x22" or just a regular crash)... What the applicationDidFinishLaunching is from my FooAppDelegate and i have no more code, is this normal ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The list of arguments passed to the `arrayWithObjects:` method must be `nil`-terminated:

```
NSArray *truc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stringMer,stringMer2, nil];
```

Comment: Note that GCC will warn you should you forget the `nil` if you compile with `-Wformat` - check out [GCC's `sentinel` function attribute][sentinel] and the header `<Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>` for `NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION`. You can also make the build fail for warnings by specifying `-Werror`.

  [sentinel]: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html "Function Attributes"

Answer (score 9):

Don't use +stringWithFormat: unless you actually have a format string that needs parsing.

Answer (score 2):

NSResponder is right - don't get sloppy by defaulting to stringWithFormat.
Perspx also pointed out a fairly obvious (but easily forgotten) error with the missing nil.

I'd be a bit more explicit -

(in the .h)

```
NSArray *truc; (assuming it won't be a property)
```

(in the .m)

```
//actually, I'd define, "OK COOL" as a string and init with that, but...
    NSString *stringMer = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"OK COOL"] ;
    NSString *stringMer2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"OK COOL"]; 


    truc = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stringMer,stringMer2, nil];

//appease the memory gods
    [stringMer release];
    [stringMer2 release];
```

(then, down in dealloc)

```
[truc release];
```

It would be good to get really familiar with Instruments - run for Leaks.